# I seem to be unable to get the length of an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create a hangman game. The idea is to have an array with different objects(puzzles). The get a puzzle from the array and show it to the user. For the user to see the number of dashes I am trying to do a for loop through the array.puzzle and make a new variable guess with a dash for every index in the array. I seem to have an error in the for loop though. I suspect I am calling the length in a wrong way maybe.

```js
console.log("Welcome to hangman type help(); for instructions!");
   
var cat = {
  puzzle: ["C", "A", "T"],
  category: "Animals",
  player: new Array(3)
}
    
var taylor = {
  puzzle: ["T", "A", "Y", "L", "O", "R", " ", "S", "W", "I", "F", "T"],
  category: "Singer",
  player: new Array(12)
}
    
taylor.player[6] = " ";
var puzzles = [cat, taylor];
//let quizz = puzzles[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
    
function start() {
  var quiz = puzzles[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  var dashes = for (var i = 0; i =< (quiz.puzzle).length; i++) {
      if(quiz.puzzle[i] = " "){
          let guess = [];
          guess.push(" ");
      } else {
          guess.push(quiz[i]);
      }
      return guess;
  }             
  console.log("The category is " + quiz.category + ": " + dashes);
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. you have a `for` in a place that it's not allowed. **HINT:** `var dashes = for`

Answer (score 0):

The for() loop does not return a value so it is incorrect to use the right hand side of an assignment.

Remove:

```
var dashes = and return guess;
```

Move:

`let guess = [];` to just before the `for()` loop.

Also:

Less Than or equal too should be: `<=` rather than `= <`

```js
console.log("Welcome to hangman type help(); for instructions!");

var cat = {
  puzzle: ["C", "A", "T"],
  category: "Animals",
  player: new Array(3)
}

var taylor = {
  puzzle: ["T", "A", "Y", "L", "O", "R", " ", "S", "W", "I", "F", "T"],
  category: "Singer",
  player: new Array(12)
}

taylor.player[6] = " ";

var puzzles = [cat, taylor];
//let quizz = puzzles[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];

function start() {
  var quiz = puzzles[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  let guess = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= (quiz.puzzle).length; i++) {
    if (quiz.puzzle[i] = " ") {
      guess.push(" ");
    } else {
      guess.push(quiz[i]);
    }
  }

  console.log("The category is " + quiz.category + ": " + dashes);
}
```